# Version of IOS for Cisco 2900 series?

Tags: cisco, router, ios

Can someone please provide the current version of IOS for the Cisco 2900 series router? I'm having trouble figuring this out based on Cisco's documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be answered by your Cisco service rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Cisco portal, it shows that the latest download for that device is 15.4.2T as of March 28, 2014.

Comment: Have in mind that in Cisco world there are multiple "current" versions. eg. in 2900 series you will find the 15.x.yM latest version which is the "stable" version and the 15.x.yT latest version which is the version with the latest features but could be a bit buggy. Usually M (maintenance) versions are recommended for production environments, especially the ones marked MD versus ED (early deployment)